# Theorem style Format

Tags: theorems

I am curious how I can make a similar format of definition and theorem as shown in the picture? Moreover, can I separate two kinds of definition or theorem format so that whenever I see fit, I use the special format?

[image]

The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
 left=1.30in,
 right=1.30in,
 }

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd} 
\usepackage{lmodern, enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} 
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} 
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} 
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} 
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}

\begin{document}
Trying to format theorem environment.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to look into using [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en); the package has very extensive documentation along with lots of examples. Try playing around with it first.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Thank you for including a description, some code and an image :) If possible, could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much, JamesT!

Comment: Off topic: several function names (`dom`, `epi``) seem to be input as ordinary math, with the result that they don't look like words, but like a string of variables.  Input them as `\mathrm{,,,}` if they should be upright, or `\mathit{...}` if they should be italic.